# Vaadin 7: Identifying a "browser back button click" through ViewChangedEvent?

Tags: java, events, vaadin

The question is more or less what the title says: I have a CustomView class that implements the View interface (Thus, the enter function, which takes a ViewChangeEvent parameter).

I'm trying to identify when the view change is triggered by an user clicking the browser "back" button (as opossite as an user clicking a link to enter that view on the application), but I've been unable to get where (if it is possible) get this information.

Am I looking into the right component? Should I look anywhere else? There's any way to find about this?

EDIT: Huh, maybe I could add a custom parameter in every, single, call to the ViewChange so I can "mark" the "normal clicks" and identify "go back/go forward" by the absence of it, but it seems like a dirty, ugly trick...

Comment: I think you are on the right track with your idea. Why do you need to distinguish them anyway?

Comment: There's a need to know when the user clicked "back" on the browser (So the application can restore view status on some of the pages), and I've been looking into how Vaadin manages view changes, to see if I can find anything.

Comment: In vaadin 7 you work with URL anchors (Part behind the #). You can either use the navigator for this, or handle them yourself. (I think is a FragmentChangeListener). In Vaadin 8.3 there is direct support for html 5 history API, which works without the # part.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to get something working, although it feels like a complete workaround, using the "changeVariables" function and some flags on parameters, on our own WhateverUI extends UI class. I have to talk with out local "Vaadin expert", if the idea works I'll answer myself next monday with what I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this will go with a bit of story, so:

I found a way to identify the "user has pressed the back button" on Vaadin, as it seems the framework manages the location change through the Page.updateLocation(String location, boolean fireEvents) function. I haven't, though, being able to modify the location parameter (This could be either due Vaadin's own architecture or due my own application specifics), so I've ended up using the function "changeVariables" on the UI class (on a inherited, own, UI class) to send a new ViewChangedEvent.

It feels a bit like a hack, but as I said, I haven't been able to make it better.

---

Going a bit into the specifics of my problem, in case someone finds it useful, I needed to identify somehow that the user was "coming back" from a different view through the "back" browser button or the "backspace" key, so I decided to used a flag on the params to indicate that the view is "retornable." This flag will have two values: "retornable" (as in "I just got into the view") and "returning" (as in "I just came back to a retornable view"). For those who will only look at code, this is what the url will show:

```
#!viewName/retflag=retornable&otherStuff=maybe
#!viewName/retflag=returning&otherStuff=perhaps
```

As I said, my "entry point" is located on "OurCustomUI" which extends UI, and had this little function:

```
@Override
public void changeVariables(Object source, Map<String, Object> variables) {
    super.changeVariables(source, variables);       
}
```

Here, the idea is getting the "location" variable from the, huh, variables Map and update it. It would be something like this:
myServer.myCompany.com/myApp/#viewName/retflag=retornable

So the code would be finding the "retflag" value, changing it to "returning", creating the ViewChangedEvent and firing it. I need to keep the super.changeVariables() call at the beginning because reasons, but it seems to work just fine as it is.